# pngquant 2.0 for ubuntu 12.04 not available

Tags: software-installation

I could not find pngquant 2.0 to install in ubuntu 12.04. I have tried version 1.0 but it has got some bugs.

Comment: What about installing from source?

Answer (score 6):

You can install pngquant 2.0 in ubuntu 12.04 using [**ppa:danmbox/ppa**](https://launchpad.net/~danmbox/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150) Repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danmbox/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pngquant
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, 2.0.1 is available in the Trusty repos. What makes this more interesting is it only depends on `libc6` and `libpng12-0`, both of which are available in 12.04. I'd be confident you could just [suck the package in from Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/pngquant).

Still, that's not a good habit to get into. You probably want to look at building it yourself.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git checkinstall libpng12-{dev,0} zlib1g-dev
git clone git://github.com/pornel/pngquant.git
cd pngquant
./configure
make
```

At this point we have a binary that works. `./pngquant --version` outputs 2.2 for me. The only bad thing is that it's only in my current directory. Personally, I have no problem with that, I can just specify the path to the binary when I need it... Or you can package it up. We installed `checkinstall` earlier which is the easiest packaging install method:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

But as I say, that's completely optional.

Comment: You can also just run `sudo make install` at the end to install it system-wide. "By default it will be installed in /usr/local/bin. To install it in another
directory run `./configure --prefix=dir && make`." (https://github.com/pornel/pngquant/blob/master/INSTALL)

Comment: @mahemoff You can but it's harder to remove. Quick and dirty packaging with `checkinstall` makes removing it trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from source following their INSTALL document from GitHub:

https://github.com/pornel/pngquant/blob/master/INSTALL

Another option would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which includes the 2.0 version.